# Send emails from IOS App

Tags: ios, parse-platform, email, sendgrid, mailgun

Hi I need to know how to send emails from my IOS app. I am using parse and they have cloud modules to intergrade Mailgun, Sendgrid etc. But there is no example code for IOS that i can see.

I have created an account with Sendgrid and need to know how to implement this with parse. I've tried to add cloud code with the parse guide but I am not getting this right.

Can someone please help to push me in the right direction to get this function in my app, any tutorials or sample code or any advice i would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

One way of sending e-mail is integrating the Mandrill with Parse. You can write a Parse cloud function which uses the Mandrill API to send email. You need to trigger the Cloud function via the İOS code. Even you can create a template in Mandrill and fill the template specific places based on specified input value. Just search on Parse tutorial. You can find examples related with cloud function and Mandrill. If you cannot find any material then please inform me so I can provide codes and links.

Hope this helps,
Regards.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply , Ive looked at Mandrill and tried to intergrade parse with mandrill but i can't get passed the cloud functions get started . Can you please help me with sample code or tutorials on how to use this in my IOS app . all i need to do is send an email , i don't need to track it or receive emails. all i want is to send an email to a specific email address . Thanx again looking forward from hearing from you. I am struggling with this as it is my first time on attempting to email from an app.

Comment: Ive also read up now about AFNetworking that i can use to send emails but that framework does not work and has a lot of problems and is not easy to use .

Comment: Dear Errol, Look at the entry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309382/mcedit-do-not-work-in-mailchimp-template-with-mandrill-javascript-api/26314942?noredirect=1#comment41314075_26314942 Hope this helps.