# mc:edit do not work in Mailchimp template with Mandrill Javascript API

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, mailchimp, mandrill

I'm trying to send emails through the Mandrill API with Mailchimp templates. I am doing this in the cloud code with Parse.com, see here https://www.parse.com/docs/cloud_modules_guide#mandrill. The emails are sent just fine, however, the mc:edit fields are never updated. This is the only content in the template now:

```
<span mc:edit="ship_id">ship_id</span>
```

This is what my call in Javascript looks like, hope somebody sees my mistake. I'm running this in Parse.com cloud code if that makes any difference. Thanks a lot!

```
var Mandrill = require('mandrill');
Mandrill.initialize('api-key');

Mandrill.sendTemplate({
    template_name: "Drip campaign",
    template_content: [{
        name: "ship_id",
        content:"Test Test"

    }],

    message: {
      text: "Hi",
      subject: "You have new mail",
      from_email: "info@example.com",
      from_name: "Thomas",
      to: [
        {
          email: "answer@example.com",
          name: "Fred"
        }
      ],
      "headers": {
          "Reply-To": "answer@example.com"
      },
      "important": false,
      "track_opens": true,
      "track_clicks": true,

    },
    async: true
    },{
    success: function(httpResponse) {

      response.success("Email sent!");
    },
    error: function(httpResponse) {
      console.error(httpResponse);
      response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Dear Marius; I think sendTemplate is in another js file and I cannot see the import(require) of this js file. Can you check this please ?

Comment: Can you check the previous comment? If this does not solve your problem then I can provide some codes where you can update the mc:edit fields. Regards.

Comment: Hi kingspeech, I'm actually using the Parse API, I updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, so there is nothing wrong with my code, but it seems like the templates are not sent properly from Mailchimp to Mandrill as adding fields such as *|NAME|* for merge tages or mc:edit="name" just were not populated. At least the code of the Mailchimp template is pretty weird and very nested.

For that reason, I would recommend using your own HTML here, where you enter the merge tages or mc:edits https://mandrillapp.com/templates/.

Comment: Dear Marius, Sorry for late reply. I update my answers in case somebody needs again. Hope you solve your problem. Regards.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand from your question that you want to send e-mail at the same time you want to dynamically edit the mail content. As you have already used, you can do it via the Mandrill API. I suggest you to use the js files which are downloadable  in the link;

https://github.com/jlainog/parse-mandrill-sendTemplate

From the js file in the github account, you can dynamically edit the mail content(must be in your template) via using the tag mc:edit.

For my case working copy of code is below;

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendMail", function(request, response) {
    var Mandrill = require('cloud/mandrillSend.js');

    var sentTo = //Mail address to sent
    var subject = //Mail Subject
    var fromEmail = //From email
    var fromName = //From Name
    var sentToName = //Parameters from request
    var fullName = //Full Name

    Mandrill.initialize('YOUR MANDRILL API KEY');
    Mandrill.sendTemplate({
        template_name: "MANDRIL TEMPLATE",
        template_content: [
        {
             name: "nameHeader",
             content: sentToName,
        },
         {
                name: "mail",
                content: sentTo,
        },
        ],
        "key": "YOUR MANDRILL API KEY",
        message: {
                subject: subject,
                from_email: fromEmail,
                from_name: fromName,
            to: [{
                email: sentTo,
                name: fullName
            }],
            important: true
        },
        async: false
    }, {
        success: function (httpResponse) {
            console.log(httpResponse);
            response.success("Email sent!");
        },
        error: function (httpResponse) {
            console.error(httpResponse);
            response.error("Uh oh, something went wrong");
        }
    });
});
```

For example, in Mandrdil Template there is a span with the id;

```
<span mc:edit="mail"> test@gmail.com</span>
```

Hope this helps.
Regards.

Comment: Dear Marius, I am using the mandrill send template js files to send mail when a new user registered to system. If you cannot  resolve the problem, then please inform me so I can provide some codes.Regards.

Comment: thanks kindspeech, I will try that out. However, where is that code coming from. I'm just wondering why it's not possible to get it work how it is described in the Parse API, but has to be used with export functions and everything.

Comment: Dear Marius, Like you, in one of the project, I need to send an e-mail when a new user registered to the system. I go on the Parse tutorial but I cannot manage to send an email with dynamically changed field. Then I look at the Parse blogs and one of the blog entry directs the link mandrill-sendTemplate. Then I succeed sending e-mail. So I want to share with you. Hope you can solve your problem. If you cannot then inform me so I can share codes with you. Regards.

Comment: hey kingspeech, it still doesn't work. The emails are sent just fine, however the mc:edit fields are never changed. Any idea what I should do now?

Comment: does it maybe have to do something with the comment in line 9 of main.js //Those are required but they are ignored?