# sending an email from Android app using Parse.com

Tags: android, email, parse-platform

I'm using Parse as my Android app server. How to send an email from the app to a given email address using Parse?

I do see some tutorial about Parse JavaScript Guide, but how to integrate it to Android development?

https://www.parse.com/docs/js/guide#cloud_modules

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you want to use Parse for sending emails?

Comment: That link is for cloud code.  If you want to send email from parse cloud code, get a mailgun account and write a cloud function that uses the mailgun module to send email.  Then call the cloud function from your Android code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Parse and Mandrill integration. However, first you have to create 
Mandrill account to get API key and template. The previous answer in the link below;

[mc:edit do not work in Mailchimp template with Mandrill Javascript API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26309382/mcedit-do-not-work-in-mailchimp-template-with-mandrill-javascript-api/26314942#26314942)

should provide necessary information. The only thing that you have to do is triggering the cloud code from code.

Hope this helps.